# ERROR server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, hive, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm running apache-hive-1.2.1-bin and spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6. spark as the hive engine. When I try to connect through JasperStudio using thrift port I get below error. I'm running ubuntu 14.04.

```
15/12/26 23:36:20 ERROR server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:268)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:328)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    ... 4 more
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO thrift.ThriftCLIService: Client protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V5
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/c670ff55-01bb-4f6f-a375-d22a13c44eaf_resources
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/anonymous/c670ff55-01bb-4f6f-a375-d22a13c44eaf
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/hduser/c670ff55-01bb-4f6f-a375-d22a13c44eaf
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/anonymous/c670ff55-01bb-4f6f-a375-d22a13c44eaf/_tmp_space.db
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Running query 'use default' with d842cd88-2fda-42b2-b943-468017e95f37
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: use default
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=Driver.run from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=compile from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=parse from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: use default
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=parse start=1451190980590 end=1451190980591 duration=1 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=semanticAnalyze from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: get_database: default
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hduser  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO DataNucleus.Query: Reading in results for query "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery@0" since the connection used is closing
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO ql.Driver: Semantic Analysis Completed
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=semanticAnalyze start=1451190980592 end=1451190980620 duration=28 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO ql.Driver: Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null, properties:null)
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=compile start=1451190980588 end=1451190980621 duration=33 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=Driver.execute from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO ql.Driver: Starting command(queryId=hduser_20151226233620_6bc633ef-5c6f-49e4-9300-f79fdf0c357b): use default
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit start=1451190980588 end=1451190980622 duration=34 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=runTasks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=task.DDL.Stage-0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO ql.Driver: Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: get_database: default
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hduser  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: get_database: default
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hduser  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=runTasks start=1451190980622 end=1451190980637 duration=15 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1451190980621 end=1451190980637 duration=16 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
OK
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO ql.Driver: OK
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1451190980639 end=1451190980639 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=Driver.run start=1451190980587 end=1451190980639 duration=52 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Result Schema: List(result#28)
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Running query 'SELECT * FROM service' with 37916038-9856-43eb-8b73-920f9faf738f
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: SELECT * FROM service
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: get_table : db=default tbl=service
15/12/26 23:36:20 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hduser  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=service  
15/12/26 23:36:20 ERROR thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error executing query, currentState RUNNING, 
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: no such table service; line 1 pos 14
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$7.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$7.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:249)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(SQLContext.scala:914)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.runInternal(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:144)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:388)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatement(HiveSessionImpl.java:369)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatement(CLIService.java:261)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:486)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1313)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1298)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/12/26 23:36:20 WARN thrift.ThriftCLIService: Error executing statement: 
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: no such table service; line 1 pos 14
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.runInternal(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:144)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:388)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatement(HiveSessionImpl.java:369)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatement(CLIService.java:261)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:486)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1313)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1298)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/12/26 23:41:08 ERROR server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:268)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:328)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    ... 4 more
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO thrift.ThriftCLIService: Client protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V5
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/aa7ce472-0284-4469-823b-748ef786ab73_resources
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/anonymous/aa7ce472-0284-4469-823b-748ef786ab73
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/hduser/aa7ce472-0284-4469-823b-748ef786ab73
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/anonymous/aa7ce472-0284-4469-823b-748ef786ab73/_tmp_space.db
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Running query 'use default' with 6a274f01-2a83-44b9-b970-2154792af7a2
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: use default
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=Driver.run from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=compile from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=parse from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: use default
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=parse start=1451191268389 end=1451191268390 duration=1 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=semanticAnalyze from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: get_database: default
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hduser  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO ql.Driver: Semantic Analysis Completed
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=semanticAnalyze start=1451191268390 end=1451191268397 duration=7 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO ql.Driver: Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null, properties:null)
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=compile start=1451191268387 end=1451191268398 duration=11 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=Driver.execute from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO ql.Driver: Starting command(queryId=hduser_20151226234108_27b4ad3d-0f88-4a81-83f6-eaf0ef49cd22): use default
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit start=1451191268387 end=1451191268399 duration=12 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=runTasks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=task.DDL.Stage-0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO ql.Driver: Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: get_database: default
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hduser  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 2: get_database: default
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hduser  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=runTasks start=1451191268399 end=1451191268412 duration=13 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1451191268398 end=1451191268412 duration=14 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
OK
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO ql.Driver: OK
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1451191268413 end=1451191268413 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=Driver.run start=1451191268387 end=1451191268413 duration=26 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
15/12/26 23:41:08 INFO thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Result Schema: List(result#43)
```

Below is the apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/conf/hive-site.xml

```
    <description>
           The cluster manager to connect to
    </description>
  </property>

   <property>
    <name>spark.serializer</name>
    <value>org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer</value>
    <description>
           Class to use for serializing objects that will be sent over the network
    </description>
  </property>



<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
  <value>NONE</value>
  <description>
    Client authentication types.
       NONE: no authentication check
       LDAP: LDAP/AD based authentication
       KERBEROS: Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication
       CUSTOM: Custom authentication provider
               (Use with property hive.server2.custom.authentication.class)
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>If true, the metastore thrift interface will be secured with SASL. Clients must authenticate with Kerberos.</description>
</property>

<!--Hive server -->
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
  <value>10000</value>
  <description>Port number of HiveServer2 Thrift interface.
  Can be overridden by setting $HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
  <value>192.168.7.87</value>
  <description>Bind host on which to run the HiveServer2 Thrift interface.
  Can be overridden by setting $HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_BIND_HOST</description>
</property>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Any news on a fix yet?

Comment: I couldn't find a fix yet and I have almost given up :-|